# How to bind to inner collection

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have lots of data like this (this is 1 from 150)

```
Name = "Andrew",
ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png",
Bad = new List<Person>
{
    new Person(){Name = "Andrew", ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png"},
    new Person(){Name = "Andrew", ImagePath = "Image/Aatrox.png"}
},
Good = new List<Person> 
{
    new Person(){Name = "Andrew", ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png"},
    new Person(){Name = "Andrew", ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png"}
}
```

I'm binding `Name` and `ImagePath` on MainPage using a `ListView`. I want to bind the `Name` and `ImagePath` properties of the `Person`'s in the lists `Bad` and `Good` to SecondPage, but I don't know how.

Update:

```
   public static Person Andrew = new Person() {Name = "Andrew", ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png"};
        public List<Models> ItemList { get; set; }

        public static List<Models> GetItems()
        {
            return new List<Models>()
            {
                new Models()
                {

                    Name = "Andrew",
                    ImagePath = "Image/Andrew.png",
                    Bad = new List<Person>
                    {Andrew, Andrew},
                    Good = new List<Person> 
                    {Andrew,Andrew}
                }
           }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem, have you tried something and got an error? Or you simply don't know the binding expression to be used to bind the inner collections?

Comment: Show us how you applied binding on MainPage and what you've tried on SecondPage. By the way: is your code snippet part of a viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you had some problem with binding to the inner collection and I happen to have some sample code on binding to inner collections

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:designDataContexts="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <designDataContexts:ViewModel x:Key="vm"/> 
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid d:DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                        </TextBlock>

                        <ListView Name="goodList" ItemsSource="{Binding Good}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </WrapPanel>                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In ViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfTests
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Models> ItemList
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Models>()
                {
                    new Models(),
                    new Models()
                };
            }
        }
    }

    class Models
    {
        public string Name { get { return "test"; } }
        public string ImagePath { get { return "image"; } }

        public List<Person> Good
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person() {Name = "Name"},
                    new Person() {Name = "Name"},
                    new Person() {Name = "Name"}
                };
            }
        }

        public List<Person> Bad
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {Name = "Name"}
            };
            }
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now notice the bindings won't update themselves unless you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModels and use ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: when an answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it as an answer (the correct mark near the question)

Comment: I have one more question... in ur answer, u give an example with datatemplate with another ListView, the problem is that i want to display a Good and Bad Listview Of SelectedItem from Listview that located on MainPage, if im using a DataTemplate Listview+Text+Image, i have Listview from all Lists Good and Bad

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but I think you would have to change your ViewModel to include a "SelectedItem" property, and then bind the UI to that property, on the ListView's SelectionChanged event, you will also have to update the "SelectedItem" property